# Autofac: регистрация типа InstancePerRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

ASP.NET WebApi2, контроллер

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IRepository Repository
    { get; set; }

    public BooksController(IRepository r)
    {
        Repository = r;
    }

    ...
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
public class BookRepository : IRepository, IDisposable
{
    public BookContext Context
    { get; set; }
     ...

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
                Context = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Контекст данных:

```
public class BookContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books
    { get; set; }
}
```

В качестве IoC используется Autofac, контейнер конфигурируется в Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{

        AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer();
        . . . 
}

public class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        builder.RegisterType<BookRepository>().InstancePerRequest().As<IRepository>().WithProperty("Context", new BookContext());

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var container = builder.Build();

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Почему-то при такой регистрации типа `BookRepository` не создается новый экземпляр его свойства `Context` с новым http-запросом. То есть первый http-запрос в API работает, а на второй возвращается такая ошибка: `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, я бы вам посоветовал переписать ваш репозиторий. В нем мне не нравится 2 вещи:

1. Инъекция в свойство. По моему мнению, если класс имеет обязательные зависимости, то они должны быть отражены в конструкторе. Иначе остается возможность создать класс и не инициализировать свойство, без которого класс не работает.
2. Второе, что мне не нравится - это ваша реализация `IDisposable`. Зачем вам делить её на 2 функции? Вы планируете в наследниках добавлять финализатор? Я так не думаю. Я бы вообще наследование от этого класса запретил.

В итоге, после моих правок, репозиторий станет выглядеть как то так:

```
public sealed class BookRepository : IRepository, IDisposable
{
    public BookRepository(BookContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    private BookContext _context;   

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context?.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }
}
```

Далее, вы регистрируете ваш репозиторий и указываете для контекста конкретное значение, которое будет использовано для всех репозиториев. Потому у вас при первом запросе контекст уничтожается при последующем уже не работает. Я не спец по autofac, но я бы зарегистрировал сначала контекст в контейнере, а потом репозиторий. Что то типа этого:

```
builder.RegisterType<BookContext>();
builder.RegisterType<BookRepository>().InstancePerRequest().As<IRepository>();
```

Никаких инъекций в свойство не надо, зависимость от контекста объявлена в конструкторе репозитория и должна подхватываться контейнером автоматом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Так всё работает: и Dispose, и контекст обновляется при последующих запросах

Comment: @WabiSabi пожалуйста